# bash. Usage of: './'

Tags: bash

I did try to find the answer online but unfortunately came up empty handed. Searching for './' in combination with other keywords brings up many hits, but none that helped...

Anyhow, as you can probably tell, I am rather new to MacOs. I am running mongo from the shell.
I cd into the /bin folder and start the mongo daemon with:

> './mongod'

.

If I just enter 'mongod', I get the following error:

> '-bash: mongod: command not found'

What does the

> './'

in './mongod' stand for? Why is it needed? Why can't I just execute mongo by typing mongod. After all, I am in the correct directory.

Comment: You might also be interested in this, [Super User: Why is . not in the path by default](http://superuser.com/questions/156582/why-is-not-in-the-path-by-default).

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of [Why do I have to use absolute path to execute bash scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143255/why-do-i-have-to-use-absolute-path-to-execute-bash-scripts)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> After all, I am in the correct directory

But that directory isn't in the `PATH`. The gist of the matter is that when the shell wants to execute something it looks into a list of directories (specified in a variable called `PATH`). **And the current directory isn't in that list**.

Comment: Very different from windows... Thanks, I understand now.

Comment: @santiagoIT In case you're interested, you *can* put `.` in `PATH` although it's quite dangerous.

Comment: In Windows, you can go into a directory and type `dir` without worrying about `dir.bat` being present. In Unix, not so.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the answer by [cnicutar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714501/cnicutar) the shell tries to match the command you enter with executables in the directories that are listed in the `PATH` environment variable.

Although you **could** add the current directory to the `PATH`, it's probably **not** a good idea to do it. This [article](http://stray-notes.blogspot.com.ar/2010/11/adding-current-directory-to-path.html) gives some good reasons why Linux doesn't add it by default:

> Its a measure to plug possible security holes. You can't run commands
>   in the current directory without specifically calling them.
>
> ie ./myscript.sh
>
> To stop nasties writing a vicious shell script, placing the script in
>   an innocent location such as /tmp and getting root to run the script.
>   Would root run a nefarious script? If the script was named 'ls' and
>   root did a listing, the script would automatically run.